# How does this implementation of full disk encryption work?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I have a laptop that has Sophos Safeguard full disk encryption on it. I booted the machine into another operating system on a USB stick and attempted to read the disk from the other OS, and I verified that the disk was encrypted and I could not read it. This machine does not have a TPM chip. I do not have to enter a PIN or a passphrase or insert a USB stick when I boot it up - it loads up the operating system seamlessly. Given these facts, where is the encryption key stored and how could it be stored securely?

Comment: If the software can indeed decrypt the disk without you entering a password or putting in a "dongle", and without network connectivity (as stated in a comment below), it's pretty obvious that the whole system is crap. The software obviously stores the key somewhere on the computer (on disk), presumably in a somewhat obfuscated way -- there is no other way they could decrypt the disk (unless everybody uses the same key...). However, if _they_ can read it, anyone with access to the computer can.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find on Sophos website, it looks like the encryption keys and revelant certificates are stored on a mssql database which holds the information.

> The SafeGuard Enterprise Database(s) hold all relevant data such as
>   keys/certificates, information about users and computers, events and
>   policy settings. The database(s) need to be accessed by the SafeGuard
>   Enterprise Server and by one security officer only through the SafeGuard
>   Management Center, usually the Master Security Officer. The SafeGuard
>   Enterprise Database(s) can be generated and configured using a wizard
>   or scripts.
>   http://www.sophos.com/en-us/medialibrary/PDFs/documentation/sgn_61_ig_eng_installation.pdf?la=en

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am sure that the Sophos client does communicate with a policy server over the network from time to time, however, I can still boot up the machine even if it is completely disconnected from the network. Therefore, the key must be stored locally... somewhere. I just don't know where or how. This is why I'm confused.

Comment: Why don't you contact Sophos support and ask them ? They are the ones who can help you, really.